# Word Tokenization using Stanford NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford-NLP Java library. I found it most accurate while dealing with stemming, lemmatization and tokenization of sentences into words.

My requirement is to tokenize words also, like "leatherjacket" can be correctly interpreted and spitted out as "leather jacket". At this level I am not dealing with spelling correction but please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question, because you are assuming you are tokenizing on words, not on tokens / raw linguistic units. Wikipedia describes tokenization as:

> In lexical analysis, tokenization is the process of breaking a stream
> of text up into words, phrases, symbols, or other meaningful elements
> called tokens.

The PTBTokenizer (CoreNLPs Primary Tokenizer) splits on *roughly words*, not actual words. Therefore the following sentence will yield 6 tokens.

> I have a really cool leatherjacket
>
> ['I', 'have', 'a', 'really', 'cool', 'leatherjacket']

Understanding that tokenization doesn't work quiet how you think, I can recommend a solution as a precursor to your tokenization process. [Peter Norvig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig) at Google who co-penned the infamous [Artifical Intelligence: A Modern approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) discussed his toy (probabilistic / discriminative) algorithm which achieves 80% - 90% accuracy. The [implementation he published is in Python](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), but has been ported to other languages which may suit your needs. Rael GC implemented a solution in Java in 42 lines which is extemely impressive on [his website](http://raelcunha.com/spell-correct.php).

Alternatively you could create your own tokenizer which goes a step further and is some sort of hybrid spelling corrector / tokenizer. However, this would be ridiculously difficult / tedious and would be publication worthy due to the novelty. But short answer, there is no golden bullet here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! Currently I am using PTBTokenizer, it works as you have mentioned. The links which you shared are good read though. I am trying to dig bit further about writing my own word segmenter or word tokenizer and spell corrector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we have anything that does that right now.  But I personally have worked on this issue before, it might be interesting to add such a component to Stanford CoreNLP.

My simple approach was basically:

1. construct a dictionary of reasonably frequent words (from Wikipedia?) (you want "leather" and "jacket" to be in the dictionary, but not "leatherjacket")
2. for a given word, generate split candidates, with a minimal size for each word (you want to split "leatherjacket" into "leather" and "jacket", you don't want to split "apolitical" into "a" and "political")
3. calculate the ratio of your smashed together word and the bigram

   (occurrences of "leather" "jacket") / (occurrences of "leatherjacket")

   If this ratio exceeds a certain threshold, replace "leatherjacket" with "leather" "jacket"
4. I generated a long list of smashed together examples and tuned my threshold based on my training data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was trying to find an algorithm which provides me the required functionality with minimal complexity and got to know about legacy dynamic programming (O(n^2)). I want to give it a shot. Thanks again for mentioning the trick.